# facebook sdk v4.2 shows Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I know this is common question, but I have read through all the stack overflow questions without finding an answer.It shows  Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton. Here my code

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/or"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/login_email_tv"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/login_email"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         />
```

and this is my basic code

public class Login_Activity extends Activity {

```
// Your Facebook APP ID
    private static String APP_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 


     CallbackManager callbackManager;

//ImageButton fb_login;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);


     FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                         // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                         // App code   
                    }
        });



}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

Any one please give me suggestions for this.Am new to android

Answer (score 0):

Have you integrated the Facebook SDK into your project? Check your `build.gradle`

You need to add the facebook module to the dependencies in `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   compile project(':facebook')
}
```

As well, the Facebook module should be imported in `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':app', ':facebook'
```

Comment: thank you for your responce.am using ecclipse.already integrated facebook sdk properly

Answer (score 0):

Initialize Facebook SDK before `SetContentView`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
 setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // App code
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                     // App code
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                     // App code   
                }
    });
 }
```